# Matlab - matrix dimensions error

Tags: matlab

I tried to write the following in Matlab

```
x=[0:0.1:1];
f=(x.^2)*sin(pi*x.^2);
```

But I was getting an error:

> Error using ***** Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: Check the size of `(x.^2)` and `sin(pi*x.^2)`. It must be n*m and m*o, which is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
f=(x.^2) * sin(pi*x.^2)'
```

This yields a scalar.

```
f=(x.^2)' * sin(pi*x.^2)
```

becomes a matrix and

```
f=(x.^2)' .* sin(pi*x.^2)
```

a vector.

Comment: I would suspect the third would be the one they are looking for.